# How to Merge two Rows as Single Row in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I have Report something like this:-
  [image]

I applied visibility False to first column value when ever we get text like `PARAMETERS` in second column and It worked but my requirement is whenever the text like `PARAMETERS` then it should be displayed as a single row.How can I do that?

Comment: can you please give example exactly what ur looking for

Comment: You can't dynamically merge cells based on content. Can you not just set the first column expression to show the 2nd column if it has `parameters` in the text. If this is no good then you'll need to somehow group your data in your dataset so each record is associated with the relevant header, then you can just use row grouping. Without seeing your available raw data it's impossible to speculate further.

Comment: You can dynamically change the border visibility which could give the appearance of a single row.

Comment: Can you modify the dataset to aggregate multiple rows into one based on your business logic? I always find it easier to play around in TSQL to get the data into a format that requires as little work as possible in SSRS.